# Ayuda con colas, JAVA

Tags: java

Tengo que hace run programa que simlue una cola, los datos de los objetos deben ser los de una persona(nombre, edad, sexo).

El programa deber insertar los datos y eliminarlos en el orden que se hace en una cola, los datos a agregar deben ser proporcionados por el usuario y la eliminación de los elementos en un ciclo.

Debe informar que elemento se agregó y que elemento se eliminó así como imprimir toda la cola después de insertar los elementos y después de haberlos eliminado todos en el ciclo.

Agradecería mucho su respuesta 
Aquí está mi código:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class MainColas {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        PERSONA obj1 = new PERSONA();
        LISTAPERSONA obj2 = new LISTAPERSONA();
        Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);
        for (int i =0; i<3; i++){       

            System.out.println("Agregue su nombre");
            String Nombre = sc.nextLine();              

            System.out.println("Inserta el sexo");  
            String Sexo = sc.nextLine();

            System.out.println("Agregue su Edad");
            String Edad = sc.nextLine();        

        obj1.setNombre(Nombre);
        obj1.setEdad(Edad);
        obj1.setSexo(Sexo);
        obj2.InsertarPersonaFinal(Nombre, Edad, Sexo);
        System.out.println("La persona que ingresó fué " +""+ obj1.getNombre() +" Años "+ obj1.getEdad() +" "+ obj1.getSexo());
        }
    }
}  

public class LISTAPERSONA {

    PERSONA PrimeraPersona;
    PERSONA UltimaPersona;
    String Lista;
    PERSONA ArregloPersonas [];
    PERSONA obj1 = new PERSONA();
        LISTAPERSONA(){
            Lista = "La listonga";


    }

        public void AgregarPersonas(int i){
            ArregloPersonas[i] = new PERSONA();

        }           

        public boolean estaVacia() {
             return PrimeraPersona == null; 
         }

         public void InsertarPersonaFinal( String n, String s, String e)
          {
             if ( estaVacia() ) 
                PrimeraPersona = UltimaPersona = new PERSONA (1);
             else 
                UltimaPersona = UltimaPersona.SiguientePersona = new PERSONA();
          }

         public PERSONA EliminarAlFinal()
          {
                 PERSONA elementoEliminado = UltimaPersona; 

                 if ( PrimeraPersona == UltimaPersona )
                     PrimeraPersona = UltimaPersona = null;
                 else
                 {
                  PERSONA actual = PrimeraPersona;                  

                 while ( actual.SiguientePersona!= UltimaPersona )
                     actual = actual.SiguientePersona;
                     UltimaPersona = actual; 
                     actual.SiguientePersona = null;
                 } 
                System.out.println("El elemento eliminado es " + elementoEliminado);
                    return elementoEliminado; 
                 }
}   

public class PERSONA {

    private int numero;
    String Nombre;
    String Sexo;
    String Edad;    
    PERSONA SiguientePersona;
    PERSONA AnteriorPersona;
    PERSONA UltimaPersona;
    PERSONA PrimeraPersona;     

    public PERSONA(){
        Nombre ="";
        Sexo = "";
        Edad = "";          
    }

    PERSONA (int num){
        this.numero = num;
        SiguientePersona = null;
        AnteriorPersona = null;
    }

    PERSONA (int num, PERSONA siguiente){
        numero = num;
        SiguientePersona = siguiente;

    }    

    public int getNumero() {
        return numero;
    }    

    public void setNumero(int numero) {
        this.numero = numero;
    }    

    public String getNombre() {
        return Nombre;
    }    

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        Nombre = nombre;
    }    

    public String getSexo() {
        return Sexo;
    }    

    public void setSexo(String sexo) {
        Sexo = sexo;
    }    

    public String getEdad() {
        return Edad;
    }    

    public void setEdad(String edad) {
        Edad = edad;
    }       
}
```

Comment: Veo la pregunta, veo el código, pero no veo que expliques cuál es tu problema.

Comment: Concuerdo con Luiggi, Creo que quiere que le agregemos esas funciones que dijo.

Comment: No exactamente, lo que pasa es que no sé si estoy agregando las personas de manera correcta además de mostrarlas, el tema de listas lo acabo de ver y no entiendo las funciones de los metodos en la clase LISTAPERSONA y PERSONA, siento que no hace lo que es :/ muchas gracias por responder

Comment: Los nombres con todas mayúsculas normalmente se utilizan para las constantes. Te recomiendo ampliamente que utilices las *Java Code Conventions* ([pdf](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-150003.pdf "Click para ver/descargar PDF")). Hay una versión en español: _Convenciones de Código para el lenguaje de programación JAVA_ ([pdf](http://www.um.es/docencia/vjimenez/ficheros/practicas/ConvencionesCodigoJava.pdf "Click para ver/descargar PDF")).

Comment: Creo que enfocas mal las clases que creas. La clase ListaPersona tiene que tener un dato miembro que sea una colección, por ejemplo una pila. Una pila saca lo último que se metió. Como el orden siempre es el de añadido, en principio, no necesitas almacenar ningún número de orden,

Answer (score 2):

Aquí tienes un pequeño ejemplo funcional de las clases que necesitas. Añade luego lo que creas conveniente pero primero fíjate bien cómo funciona. He utilizado una pila (Stack) de tipo LIFO que significa que lo último en entrar es lo primero en salir. Si necesitas otro tipo de pila o colección, busca información por ejemplo [aquí](https://www.adictosaltrabajo.com/tutoriales/introduccion-a-colecciones-en-java/)

```
public class Persona {

    // Los datos miembro hazlos siempre privados
    // Inicializa siempre los datos miembro
    private String Nombre = "";
    private String Sexo = "";
    private String Edad = "";

    Persona (String Nombre, String Sexo, String Edad){
        this.Nombre = Nombre;
        this.Sexo = Sexo;
        this.Edad = Edad;
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return Nombre;
    }    

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        Nombre = nombre;
    }    

    public String getSexo() {
        return Sexo;
    }    

    public void setSexo(String sexo) {
        Sexo = sexo;
    }    

    public String getEdad() {
        return Edad;
    }    

    public void setEdad(String edad) {
        Edad = edad;
    }           
}

public class ListaPersonas {
    private Stack<Persona> pila = new Stack();  

    void AñadirPersona(Persona nuevaPersona){
        pila.push(nuevaPersona);
    }

    Persona ConsultarÚltimaPersona(){
        return pila.peek();  
    }

    Persona SacarÚltimaPersona(){
        return pila.pop();
    }

    int BuscarPosiciónPersona(Persona persona){
      return pila.search(persona);
    }
}
```

Finalmente, en el método main:

```
   // creamos unos cuantos objetos 'Persona'
    Persona persona1 = new Persona("David","Hombre","30");
    Persona persona2 = new Persona("Montse","Mujer","25");
    Persona persona3 = new Persona("Pablo","Hombre","10");

    // creamos una 'lista' de 'Persona's
    ListaPersonas lista = new ListaPersonas();
    lista.AñadirPersona(persona1);
    lista.AñadirPersona(persona2);
    lista.AñadirPersona(persona3);

    // Ver la última persona introducida:
    System.out.println ("Última persona: " + lista.ConsultarÚltimaPersona().getNombre()); 

    // Sacar la última persona de la lista:
    System.out.println ("Eliminada la persona: " + lista.ConsultarÚltimaPersona().getNombre()); 

    // Buscar la posición de una persona en la lista:
    System.out.println ("Posición de Montse: " + lista.BuscarPosiciónPersona(persona2));
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar la implementación que propone @Oundroni, lo que con algunos cambios. Primero, si lo que deseas es un comportamiento de cola, utiliza

```
 LinkedList<Persona> cola=new LinkedList<Persona>()
```

En la clase `ListarPersonas`, pues esta estructura de datos te permite un comportamiento de cola, además tiene implementado varios métodos como el `.add()` para adicionar como una cola, con los métodos `.getFirst()` y `.getLast()` puedes obtener el primero y ultimo elemento, además implementa los métodos de cola `.poll()` `.peek()`.